# preventDefault when clicking bounty "cancel" link

Tags: feature-request, bounty-dialog

When you click "start a bounty" then "cancel," `href="#"` exiles you to the top of the page and you lose your spot near the end of the question's comments. Clicking anywhere else on the page simply closes the bounty popup; clicking "cancel" ought to do the same.

In case that wasn't clear:

[image: goodbye comments]

Dramatization aside, it's a nuisance. Can the `click` event on that anchor be `preventDefault`ed?