# Dismissing the cookie popup with the "X" scrolls the page to the top

Tags: bug, popups, cookies

Similar to [preventDefault when clicking bounty "cancel" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215907/preventdefault-when-clicking-bounty-cancel-link) (which was fixed), when you click the "X" on the upper right of the cookie popup:

[image]

The unnecessary `href="#"` line flings you to the top of the page and thus makes you lose sight of the answer or comment you were looking at.  Clicking anywhere closes the popup without this behavior, so clicking the "X" should do the same, or it shouldn't be there at all, given that there is a "Cancel" button alongside the others that doesn't do this:

[image]

Small thing, but there are those who actually use the exes, so can this be fixed?